# How do I convert special characters from an <input> into an escape sequence

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a barcode application whereby the user has the ability to specify termination characters.

Consider the following:

```
<input id="terminators" type="text" value="\n" />
```

When I read the value from the input, the escape sequence `\n` is returned as two individual characters `\` and `n`. Whereas I need it as one `\n` *(ASCII character 10)*.

You can reproduce this issue the browsers console:

```
document.getElementById('terminators').value.charCodeAt(0) === '\n'.charCodeAt(0);
```

Comment: Please clarify get your question, as in expected vs actual result.

Comment: What does the length of the input's value have to do with using its value as a character?

Comment: Not at all clear what you are asking

Comment: Sorry, I was struggling to explain the issue which is probably half the issue - updated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The value of an input is escaped with an additional `\`, so `\n` becomes `\\n`:

We can validate this using the following test:

```
document.getElementById('terminators').value.charCodeAt(0) === '\\n'.charCodeAt(0)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v9b348z3/